# JQuery Flot X axis label formatting

Tags: jquery, flot

I have more no of ticks for x axis labels in the date format. Now i need to format it with Year or Month or Week based on the number of ticks generated dynamically. For example, if i have dates 2011-10-01,2011-10-02,......2015-10-05, then i need to format the x axis label as 2011, 2012, 2013,...2015. As i am making line graph, when i click the circle, it should show the actual values in the tool tip. i.e. 2011-01-10: 200. Now the x axis labels are merged one with another.

I have tried creating ticks with only year been displayed, but in the tooltip its not getting reflected. i.e. empty.

[image]

Kindly share thoughts how can i produce it in good manner.

Comment: add  fiddle from sample data if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the options for timeformat and minTickSize depending on your data with a function like this:

```
var diff = data[data.length - 1][0] - data[0][0];
var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

if (diff < 31 * oneDay) {
    options.xaxis.minTickSize = [1, 'day'];
    options.xaxis.timeformat = '%Y-%m-%d';
} else if (diff < 24 * 31 * oneDay) {
    options.xaxis.minTickSize = [1, 'month'];
    options.xaxis.timeformat = '%Y-%m';
} else {
    options.xaxis.minTickSize = [1, 'year'];
    options.xaxis.timeformat = '%Y';
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLeccdvy/) for a full example.

Comment: How will the tool tip work for this? whether it will display real value in the tooltip? or formatted value. I need real value.

Comment: Depending on which tooltip plugin you use you may have to format it differently, but the real value is there. Try implementing it in the fiddle and if you have further questions come back here.